# Facebook developer account, all apps disappeared

Tags: facebook

I am a mobile developer and I frequently use facebook to add sharing feature to my applications.

I usually have alot of applications on my facebook developer account.

But today all my apps have disappeared and my account seems to not be a developer account.

When I click on the "Applications" menu (on https://developers.facebook.com/) I only see "Register as a Developer" in the dropdown menu.

Someone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue. If there was a violation - and I don't think there was as the app is in sandbox - I received no notification of this. The literature states that an app will be disabled, not that an entire developer account will be removed. As I have other active apps this is quite a problem. It seems I can set up another developer account but one assume all existing apps will need to be set back up. Clusterf**k

UPDATE:

I re-signed up as a developer and all my apps are still there. A fright, but better that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not registered to accept payments. I couldn't find a hint of official support on the subject of 'closed developer accounts' nor any real way to directly engage other than firing off a bug report. As I said, re-registering did the trick and they just asked for a few bits of info.